# Is there a way to convert results returned from bigquery to Json format using Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-bigquery

Currently using python to pull data from bigquery after getting the result need to convert it in JSON format.How to convert the result to JSON ?

```
 query_job2 = client_bq.query(query)
    query_job2.result()
    rows = list(query_job2.result())  # Waits for query to finish
    response = dict()
    """
    Creating a nested dictionary with the tables as the keys and inside each respective table will hold cost as keys and
    have a list of values
    """
    for row in rows:
        table = get_table_name(str(row.query))
        start_time =int(row.start_time.timestamp())
        end_time =int(row.end_time.timestamp())

        if table in response:
            if row.cost in response[table]:
                response[table] = list(response[table])
                response[table].append((str(row.creation_time),start_time,end_time , row.cost, str(row.query)))
        else:
            response[table] = {}
            response[table] = (str(row.creation_time), start_time,end_time, row.cost, str(row.query))
```

here is the query i am using :

```
     with data AS (
       SELECT
       creation_time,
       total_bytes_processed,
       query
       FROM `project.region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT`
       where creation_time > TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -60 SECOND)  AND job_type = "QUERY"
       Group BY creation_time,  job_id, total_bytes_processed, query
       ORDER BY total_bytes_processed DESC
)
select as value
  array_agg(struct( creation_time,
       regexp_extract(query, r'(?i)\sfrom\s+`?(?:[\w-]+\.)*([\w-]+\.[\w-]+)`?\s' ) as table,
       (total_bytes_processed/1099511627776) * 5 as cost,
       query) order by (total_bytes_processed/1099511627776) * 5  desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from data
group by timestamp_trunc(creation_time, minute)
    """
```

Comment: The question can be phrased better. You are asking how to format a pandas.DataFrame as a json. You can do it by calling df.to_json(orient=....). It has nothing to do with BigQuery since you could have equivently read the data from a CSV for example.

Comment: @gidutz Really interesting  i figured maybe I can get the results directly from a query or something  or convert the row.iterator object into a dictionary  or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question can be separated into two parts:

1. How to read data from Google BigQuery to Pandas. You can find the answer [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#standard-sql-query)

   ```py
   from google.cloud import bigquery

   client = bigquery.Client()
   query_sql = """SELECT col FROM `table`"""

   df = client.query(query_sql).to_dataframe()
   ```
2. After you obtain the data in a pandas object you can use the `to_json` method to convert it to a json string:

   ```py
   df.to_json(orient='index')
   ```

Alternatively you can export data directly from BigQuery as JSON files, either from the UI as shown [here](https://dataform.co/blog/exporting-data-bigquery) or using a python client.

The first method is better if you need to manipulate the data in memory using pandas, the second method will allow you to serialize your data for a much greater scale.